# Работа с iframe, работа с урл, get, post

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Подгружаеться iframe окно, в этом айфрейм окне методом пост, я достаю данные с урла, так как у айфрейма свой урл, я не могу увидеть данные самого окна. Пытался обратным способом достучаться с окна к айфрейму, js сбоит, и не меняет значение в коде.

код скрипта

```
$(Ссылка ниже)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebfhcgc2/

Comment: PHP кода нету, кто разбирается и без него понятно))

Comment: Доступ из iframe к внешнему документу (и наоборот) запрещён политикой безопасности браузеров

Comment: Спасибо! А я все бьюсь и бьюсь, в потолок.